# how to change the attributes of child divs from the parent div through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
#va{
  color:yellow; 
 
}
#v{
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div id = "va">   
  <div id ="v">my name is </div>
  <div>khan</div>      
</div>
```

i have tried using document.getelementbyid("va").style.color="yellow"; but the color of element v is not changing i want to change its color by the id of parent i want it to be done through javascript as it is the simple example of the situation in which i am traped plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#va>#v").css("background-color","green")
```

```css
#va{
  color:yellow; 
 
}
#v{
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "va">   asdasd
  <div id ="v">my name is </div>
  <div>khan</div>      
</div>
```

1. Use `>` the direct child selector.
2. The selector will select the direct child(with id v) of element with id va and change color to red

Answer (score 0):

With **jquery** you have two options, using the [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method or using [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method, take a look in this snippet:

```js
$("#va").children().css("color", "red");
//$("#va").find("#v").css("color","blue");
```

```css
#va {
  color: yellow;
}

#v {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="va">
  <div id="v">
    my name is
  </div>
  <div>
    khan
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of ID `v`, use `getElementById("v")` rather that `getElementById("va")`

```js
document.getElementById("v").style.color = "yellow";
```

```css
#va {
  color: yellow;
}

#v {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="va">
  <div id="v">my name is </div>
  <div>khan</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the class attribute of any element and create the css to what you need using:

```
document.getElementById("va").setAttribute("class", "yellow-class");
```

css would bw something like:

```
.yellow-class{
    color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Colors styles only affect child nodes if the child node's color property is set to initial.

```
#va{
  color:yellow; 
}
#v{
  color:initial;
}
```

However, this will remove the default pink color from your tag. There are lots of different ways you could solve this problem but the simplest would be to just create a new style rule and simply use js to add a class to `#va` to change the style.

```
#va.yellow #v {
  color: yellow;
}
```

And use this js.

```
document.getElementById("va").className += " yellow";
```